# Why doesn't collections.Counter override __iadd__ method?

Tags: python, counter

It seems quite frequently used case of merging several `Counter`s together couldn't be performed using builtin operations without much extra work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter.update`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update):

```
>>> c = Counter('aaab')
>>> c.update(Counter('babac'))
>>> c
Counter({'a': 5, 'b': 3, 'c': 1})
```

In Python 3.3, `__iadd__` is overriden: (http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/5cced40374df)

```
>>> sys.version
'3.3.0 (default, Sep 29 2012, 17:14:58) \n[GCC 4.7.2]'
>>> print(Counter.__iadd__.__doc__)
Inplace add from another counter, keeping only positive counts.

        >>> c = Counter('abbb')
        >>> c += Counter('bcc')
        >>> c
        Counter({'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'a': 1})
```